# Problem with metric and imperial measurements

Tags: modeling

siljelb, thank you for your info. I wasn't;t able to accomplish because of my lack of familiarization. But I found another explanation which made it easy of rme to understand. Thanks very much and I don't know how to give you a thumbs up

But here is the one I found most helpful
[How to set Object Dimension](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31367/how-to-set-object-dimension)

Just beginning Blender learning

In Layout, Edit Mode/Orthographic, I can see after changing the cube to a rectangular shape (looks like a shoe box lid), using Cube>Transform>Scale X,Y,Z to 0.5, 12.o 6.0 (changed from metric to Imperial) consecutively. But after I use letter A to show dimensions, all dimension are 12".

I need x=4", Y=12" z=6"

And even when I scale the measurements do not change. I realize I'm missing a detail that several videos aren't covering or I'm not absorbing

I'm going to close and Save As so I can reopen, which I'm learning well.

As a newbie, for someone to close my question, in less than 24 hours, without enough detail needed, is disheartening, and did not answer my question. So to whoever closed my question, please understand that this is not all I do during a 24 hour time span.

I wouldn't have minded waiting for a few days to get answer. I'm a slow learner. If this is Ai, then I won't do well here in this forum. I'm barely capable of asking a clear question and not at all familiar with how to navigate this forum yet.

How about a little patience for an old timer

[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying the scale? *Object > Apply > Scale*

Comment: @siljelb Yes as I originally stated " using Cube>Transform>Scale X,Y,Z to 0.5, 12.o 6.0 (changed from metric to Imperial) consecutively. But after I use letter A to show dimensions, all dimension are 12""

Comment: but further after entering size dimensions in Cube>Transform>Mode>XYZ Euler, all dimensions show as 12" when I actually had put it in as X 0.50"x Y 12.0 x Z 6.0 thinking these would get me inches. Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: @Invent-A-Thing From what I gather from your questions, I still think the link we've previously pointed you towards has your answer. However, I understand that can be overwhelming when you're a beginner who's probably confused about certain fundamentals. May I suggest you watch some videos about them before anything else? Here's a good, detailed series about "beginner traps": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsXSXnMpT9A

Answer (score 0):

Because you scaled your original Cube object in Object mode the mesh is still showing the original dimensions in Edit mode.
To correct this, in Object mode you need to Apply the X Y and Z scale.
See screen-shots below :

Not sure why my default cube is 24" X 24" x 24" when yours is 12" but doesn't matter for this example :
[image]

Resizing the Cube in Object mode:
[image]

In Edit mode the mesh is still indicating the original dimensions :
[image]

To fix this we need to Apply the Scale in Object mode :
[image]

Now Scale is 1.000 in Object mode :
[image]

and dimensions correct in Edit mode:
[image]

To avoid this issue, best is, whenever possible, do all your mesh editing in Edit mode.

As a general rule always check that your objects scale (in Object mode),is at 1.000 before using Modifiers and UV unwrapping etc.)

A video that attempts to explain this Object mode v Edit mode thing in Blender :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsXSXnMpT9A

The keyboard shortcut to open the **Apply menu** is **Ctrl A**

Comment: That certainly looks like what I want. But I'll need to spend some time at this because I don't think I used your suggestions. I'm learning but limping along at best and very very early in this. Thanks very much for the very clear detail and professional instructions with arrows and text and the link to a video. Most helpful