Problem sculpting large scale flat surface
I try to create a surface of a little larger garden by hand.
It should be have about 150m x 300m in size and needs some smaller hills on it.
I want to use the sculpt tools for that.

I created a cube and
made it flat and large (The dimensions mentioned above and 50m in height)
I sculpted (grab) it once and pulled it up:



Then I grab it a second time at the already pulled area and pull it up again in the same direction as the first grab. This time the result is not as smooth grab as the first one:


Only small spikes are moved.
Doing this with the same cube in a smaller scale (1m³) works perfectly:

The radius also looks totally different when in larger scale:

than in smaller scale:

I already subdivided the cube more to check if it has to do with the subdivision count - without success.
This does not happen with large spheres with 300m in diameter somehow.
Before I create a bug, has someone an idea why that happens?

Why a cube instead of a grid? Are you scaling the vertical size to zero?

Did you apply the scale after sizing it up that much? Non standard scale messes with sculpt tools

@TheLabCat: I tried a grid, too. Same problem. Sphere works.
edit: I tried some vertical sizes like 2m and 50m without success.

@Jakemoyo: I use the "dimensions" to scale it. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31367/how-to-set-object-dimension

Is there a different way? I thought dimensions and scale are directly linked.

@Jakemoyo: Applying the scale helps. Thank you both for helping me. If you answer this question I'll accept it.

I'm not sure why you're using sculpting for this. Personally I'd turn on Proportional Editing, grab a single vertex and move it up changing the influence with the mouse wheel.

I didn't know that this is an alternative, too. Thanks, I'll try that. Seems to be a more structured approach.

Blender docs: Proportional Editing and there are lots of online tutorials.

After applying the scale, the problem was solved.
Thanks to the comment of Jakemoyo.
